# How to save downloaded software?

Tags: software-recommendation, package-management

I am totally new to Ubuntu and my Internet connection is slow. Because of that, I can't afford to download software twice. When I install Ubuntu again for some reason, I want to know how to save the downloaded software so I can install it again. I don't understand how to install software as well.

If someone can suggest me software for video and audio codec, download accelerator, that would be useful.

Comment: What version Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are downloading the software from Software-center/Synaptic that will be at  `/var/cache/apt/archives` of your Ubuntu PC . you can get them and save .
2. if you want to install any software you have three things

   i. Software-center
      ii.Synaptic package manager
      iii. Terminal methods if installing

Software-center and Synaptic and GUI based application and you can install applications from there with a Click .

Terminal ways are two .

```
            i. apt-get
            ii.aptitude
```

for **apt-get**

```
sudo apt-get install <application/package_name>
```

GUIDE: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

there in the glides you can place what ever the software you want to install .

for **aptitude**

```
sudo aptitude install <pkgname>
```

GUIDE: https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/aptitude.html

here you have to mention the name , similar to apt-get .

but in apt-get and aptitude i vote for apt-get .

Best Audio/Video Software  , i always use **VLC player** (available in software center ) but we have more examples smplayer etc.

Download accelerators : I use wget (a CLI based ) but we have GUI also i vote for fatrat and deluge for torrent downloads .

Comment: @rakibul, the wget usage would be as follows:-   wget <download url/link>. If you want GUI i would recommend uget/steady flow download manager for audio; For video go video download helper addon in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

First for video, audio codec i suggest you to install [VLC](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc) [image: Install vlc]

Or if you want to use the default applicaions in ubuntu, install from the software center `ubuntu-restricted-extras`

[image: Install via the software center]

Or from Terminal

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

That will install every codecs you need + some fonts and flash player....

---

To setup a software offline you can make it either by downloawding debain package of your software so you can setup on an another pc's but you must be aware of the dependencies. Or you can make your own repository but this needs a fast internet and much space.
To install a software you can do it in many ways:

1. graphically you can use the software center (easy and flexible way)
2. CLI by using apt-get example sudo  apt-get install pkgname ...this command will  install a package called pkgname
3. you can also use synaptic but since it's not founded by default from ubuntu 11.04 and more so you need to get it first so from software center type synaptic and you can get it. now you can use it (for me i preffer it on ubuntu software center
   )

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1 : Saving software for re installation**

Solutions:

1. Manual Method - Copy files inside `/var/cache/apt/archives` to back up location.After re installation copy them back. Try to install using `apt-get`. You will avoid large downloads.
2. Backup Tools -

Option 1 (*Recomended*) : Install everything required in your system. Use [remastersys](http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu.html) to take backup of everything and create an ISO. Use this ISO to reinstall ubuntu. This way every software will be pre - installed.

Option 2 : Use [keryx](http://keryxproject.org/). Use this tool to download software from other computer (with fast internet) and install in your own computer.

**Q2**

Install Vlc and `ubuntu-restricted-extras` . All common video and audio will run smoothly.

I use firefox, and `downthemall` addon is my choice. Alternative - `wget` / `uget`